# getting needed documents with limit

Tags: mysql, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using Mongodb, but I can migrate to mysql, My problem is, I have a collection which consists datas like this one,

```
array(
"L"=>"cars",
"M"=>"wolkswagen"
)
array(
"L"=>"cars",
"M"=>"bmw"
)
array(
"L"=>"cars",
"M"=>"mercedes"
)


array(
"L"=>"bike",
"M"=>"bianchi"
)
array(
"L"=>"bike",
"M"=>"trek"
)
array(
"L"=>"bike",
"M"=>"brook"
)
```

What I want to get as a result, any bike and car, but 2 results for each of them, so the result should be,

```
array(
"L"=>"cars",
"M"=>"some car"
)
array(
"L"=>"cars",
"M"=>"some car"
)


array(
"L"=>"bike",
"M"=>"some bike"
)
array(
"L"=>"bike",
"M"=>"some bike"
)
```

I tried to do this with $in, but does not seem to work, any ideas ?

Comment: You will want to make two queries and use `limit`, like: `$db->col->find(array('L' => 'bike'))->limit(2);` and `$db->col->find(array('L' => 'cars'))->limit(2);` mongodb has no way to limit specific clauses yet.

Comment: I have 16 of those, It is not a good idea, I have to figure out another way out, thank you :)

Comment: Well I am unsure what else you can do here, I suppose you could change your schema but to what I am unsure. I am not even sure that MySQL supports this actually without some butchery of it's performance

Comment: Does each element in your example array represent a separate document (i.e. you have six documents), or are they stored as an array in a single document?  Also, do you care which two elements you get for each value of L, or would any two do?

Comment: @Stennie yes they represent a seperate document

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve this problem using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2+.

Unfortunately the Aggregation Framework as at 2.2.2 doesn't support a `$slice` or array subset operator yet, so some extra manipulation is required.

Note: The examples below are using the `mongo` shell, but should be straightforward to translate to the PHP driver.

#### Example #1: use Aggregation Framework to extract two matches (first & last)

Assuming you aren't fussed which two elements you get for each grouping, you could select the `$first` and `$last`:

```
db.cars.aggregate(

    // Group by $L and find the first and last elements
    { $group: {
        _id: '$L',
        first: { $first: "$M" },
        last: { $last: "$M" },
    }},

    // Add an extra $index for # of array elements
    { $project: {
        first: 1,
        last: 1,
        index: { $const:[0,1] }     
    }},

    // Split into document stream based on $index
    { $unwind: '$index' },

    // Re-group data using conditional to create array 
    { $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        M: {
            $push: { $cond:[ {$eq:['$index', 0]}, '$first', '$last'] }
        }
    }}
)
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "cars",
            "M" : [
                "wolkswagen",
                "mercedes"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "bike",
            "M" : [
                "bianchi",
                "brook"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

#### Example #2: use Aggregation Framework to create a set, and then reduce

An alternative to the above would be a simpler pipeline with `$addToSet` and a post-processing step to trim the array elements:

```
var agg = db.cars.aggregate(
    { $group: {
        _id: '$L',
        'M': { $addToSet: "$M" },
    }}
)

// Iterate to trim each result to the desired # of elements
agg.result.forEach(function(doc) {
    // Note: you could randomly select 2 (or n) elements here
    doc.M = doc.M.slice(0,2);
})
```

The output format will be the same as with example #1, but instead of selecting the first & last elements, example #2 (as written) selects the first two elements.

Comment: Please vote/watch the related MongoDB feature request [SERVER-4589: aggregation: need an array indexing operator](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589).